# 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text' in Kivy

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language

I am new to Kivy and I am trying to get a file's path and copy it to a TextInput using FileChooserIconView. But when I double click a file, I got this error message "'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'". I am unable to solve it. I really really need help.

My code is:

```
from kivy.config import Config
Config.set('graphics', 'resizable', False)
Config.set('graphics', 'width', '500')
Config.set('graphics', 'height', '700')
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty


Window.clearcolor = (1, 1, 1, 1)


class Window(Widget):
    label = ObjectProperty(None)
    def popup_open(self):
        self.popup = FolderPopup()
        self.popup.open()

class FolderPopup(Popup):
    window = Window()



class GUI(App):
    def build(self):
        return Window()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    GUI().run()
```

My .kv file is:

```
<FolderPopup>:
    size_hint: (None, None)
    size: (500, 500)
    title: "Choose a File"
    BoxLayout:
        FileChooserIconView:
            on_selection: root.window.label.text = self.selection

<Window>:

    label: label

    GridLayout:
        size: 500, 700
        cols: 1
        TextInput:
            text: "Please choose a file."
            multiline: False
            halign: "center"
            readonly: True
            color: 0, 0, 0, 1
            id: label
            size_hint: root.width, None
            size: 0, 35

        Button:
            text: "Choose a File"
            size: root.width, 10
            on_release: root.popup_open()
            size_hint: root.width, None
            size: 0, 30
```

Sorry i forgot to post the traceback. Here is the traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "D:\PyCharm\Converter\Main.py", line 31, in <module>
     GUI().run()
   File "D:\PyCharm\Converter\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\app.py", line 950, in run
     runTouchApp()
   File "D:\PyCharm\Converter\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\base.py", line 582, in runTouchApp
     EventLoop.mainloop()
   File "D:\PyCharm\Converter\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\base.py", line 347, in mainloop
     self.idle()
   File "D:\PyCharm\Converter\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\base.py", line 391, in idle
     self.dispatch_input()
   File "D:\PyCharm\Converter\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\base.py", line 342, in dispatch_input
     post_dispatch_input(*pop(0))
   File "D:\PyCharm\Converter\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\base.py", line 248, in post_dispatch_input
     listener.dispatch('on_motion', etype, me)
   File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 709, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch
   File "D:\PyCharm\Converter\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\window\__init__.py", line 1416, in on_motion
     self.dispatch('on_touch_up', me)
   File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 709, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch
   File "D:\PyCharm\Converter\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\window\__init__.py", line 1452, in on_touch_up
     if w.dispatch('on_touch_up', touch):
   File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 709, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch
   File "D:\PyCharm\Converter\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\uix\modalview.py", line 284, in on_touch_up
     super(ModalView, self).on_touch_up(touch)
   File "D:\PyCharm\Converter\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\uix\widget.py", line 567, in on_touch_up
     if child.dispatch('on_touch_up', touch):
   File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 709, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch
   File "D:\PyCharm\Converter\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\uix\widget.py", line 567, in on_touch_up
     if child.dispatch('on_touch_up', touch):
   File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 709, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch
   File "D:\PyCharm\Converter\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\uix\widget.py", line 567, in on_touch_up
     if child.dispatch('on_touch_up', touch):
   File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 709, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch
   File "D:\PyCharm\Converter\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\uix\widget.py", line 567, in on_touch_up
     if child.dispatch('on_touch_up', touch):
   File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 709, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch
   File "D:\PyCharm\Converter\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\uix\filechooser.py", line 563, in on_touch_up
     return super(FileChooserController, self).on_touch_up(touch)
   File "D:\PyCharm\Converter\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\uix\relativelayout.py", line 313, in on_touch_up
     ret = super(RelativeLayout, self).on_touch_up(touch)
   File "D:\PyCharm\Converter\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\uix\widget.py", line 567, in on_touch_up
     if child.dispatch('on_touch_up', touch):
   File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 709, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch
   File "D:\PyCharm\Converter\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\uix\widget.py", line 567, in on_touch_up
     if child.dispatch('on_touch_up', touch):
   File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 709, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch
   File "D:\PyCharm\Converter\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\uix\scrollview.py", line 950, in on_touch_up
     if self.dispatch('on_scroll_stop', touch):
   File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 709, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch
   File "D:\PyCharm\Converter\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\uix\scrollview.py", line 989, in on_scroll_stop
     self.simulate_touch_down(touch)
   File "D:\PyCharm\Converter\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\uix\scrollview.py", line 668, in simulate_touch_down
     ret = super(ScrollView, self).on_touch_down(touch)
   File "D:\PyCharm\Converter\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\uix\widget.py", line 545, in on_touch_down
     if child.dispatch('on_touch_down', touch):
   File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 709, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch
   File "D:\PyCharm\Converter\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\uix\scatter.py", line 526, in on_touch_down
     if super(Scatter, self).on_touch_down(touch):
   File "D:\PyCharm\Converter\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\uix\widget.py", line 545, in on_touch_down
     if child.dispatch('on_touch_down', touch):
   File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 709, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch
   File "D:\PyCharm\Converter\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\uix\widget.py", line 545, in on_touch_down
     if child.dispatch('on_touch_down', touch):
   File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 705, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch
   File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 1248, in kivy._event.EventObservers.dispatch
   File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 1132, in kivy._event.EventObservers._dispatch
   File "D:\PyCharm\Converter\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\lang\builder.py", line 57, in custom_callback
     exec(__kvlang__.co_value, idmap)
   File "D:\PyCharm\Converter\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\data\style.kv", line 398, in <module>
     on_touch_down: self.collide_point(*args[1].pos) and ctx.controller().entry_touched(self, args[1])
   File "D:\PyCharm\Converter\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\uix\filechooser.py", line 627, in entry_touched
     self.selection = [abspath(join(self.path, entry.path)), ]
   File "kivy\properties.pyx", line 498, in kivy.properties.Property.__set__
   File "kivy\properties.pyx", line 840, in kivy.properties.ListProperty.set
   File "kivy\properties.pyx", line 545, in kivy.properties.Property.set
   File "kivy\properties.pyx", line 600, in kivy.properties.Property.dispatch
   File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 1248, in kivy._event.EventObservers.dispatch
   File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 1130, in kivy._event.EventObservers._dispatch
   File "D:\PyCharm\Converter\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\lang\builder.py", line 57, in custom_callback
     exec(__kvlang__.co_value, idmap)
   File "D:\PyCharm\Converter\gui.kv", line 7, in <module>
     on_selection: root.window.label.text = self.selection
 AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'
```

Comment: Post the full traceback. Also which object is null?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `window` that you create in the `FolderPopup` class with the line:

```
window = Window()
```

is a new instance of `Window` and has is not connected to the `Window` that is the root of your GUI. You can access the correct instance of `Window` as `app.root` in your `kv`. The `FolderPopup` class can be simplified:

```
class FolderPopup(Popup):
    pass
```

And the `kv` can use `app.root` to access the `Window` instance:

```
<FolderPopup>:
    size_hint: (None, None)
    size: (500, 500)
    title: "Choose a File"
    BoxLayout:
        FileChooserIconView:
            on_selection: app.root.label.text = self.selection[0]
```

Also, note that the `FileChooser` selection is always a list.

You might consider changing the name of your `Window` class (just to avoid possible confusion) since `Window` is an important class already defined by kivy.